# A method to sum all values in a returned column using Cypher in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have written the following Cypher query to get the frequency of a certain item from a set of orders.

```
MATCH (t:Trans)-[r:CONTAINS]->(i:Item) 
WITH i,COUNT(*) AS CNT,size(collect(t)) as NumTransactions 
RETURN i.ITEM_ID as item, NumTransactions, NumTransactions/CNT as support
```

I get a table like this as my output

```
Item NumTransactions Support
A          2            1
B        1132           1
C        2049           1
```

And so on. What I mean to do is divide each NumTransaction by the total number of transactions. i.e. the sum of the entire num transactions column, to get the support but instead it divides NumTransactions by itself. Can someone point me to the correct function if it exists or an approach to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (:Trans)-[:CONTAINS]->(i:Item) 
WITH i, COUNT(*) as c
WITH COLLECT({i: i, c: c}) AS data
WITH data, REDUCE(s = 0.0, n IN data | s + n.c) AS total
UNWIND data AS d
RETURN d.i.ITEM_ID as item, d.c AS NumTransactions, d.c/total as support
```

*By the way, `SIZE(COUNT(t))` is inefficient, as it first creates a new collection of `t` nodes, gets its size, and then deletes the collection. `COUNT(t)` would have been more efficient.*

*Also, given your `MATCH` clause, as long as every `t` has at most a single `CONTAINS` relationship to a given `i`, `COUNT(*)` (which counts the number of result rows) would give you the same result as `COUNT(t)`.*

Comment: Oh, I did not know that the collection would be deleted. Reduce was exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much for the clarification. It was very helpful